# Need to edit this XML file with powershell

Tags: powershell, xml

I have an XML file and need to change the value to False. Is there a way to do this with powershell?

```
<setting name="RecordChatHistory">
    <value>True</value>
  </setting>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way.

1. Loading xml

   `$xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path C:\path\to\file.xml)`
2. Replacing string value *True* to *False*

   `$xml.setting.value = 'False'`
3. Using the Save() method

   `$xml.Save("C:\path\to\file.xml")`

Comment: Thanks, But there are multiple value tags. I don't want to replace them all.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the question... for more advanced filtering of xml you could look into XPath

Comment: @MichaelX this does answer your question. Please accept the answer, then ask a new question with the right information and what you seek.